# I can not display the password field input (with 'repeat' option) with twig (Symfony2)

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I have the following form and Twig template:

**FormType**

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{ 
/**
* @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
* @param array $options
*/
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder

        ->add('name','text',array('label' => 'Name', 'max_length' => 30))
        ->add('surname','text',array('label' => 'Sjurname', 'max_length' => 30))
        ....

        ->add('password', 'repeated', array('error_bubbling' => true,'required' => false, 'first_options'  => array('label' => 'New Password'),'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat Password'),'type' => 'password' ,'invalid_message'=> 'Passwords must be the same.'));
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Bundle\Entity\User',
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'user';
}
```

}

**Twig**

```
  ....

  {{form_start(form, {'method':'Put','attr':{'data-toggle':"validator", 'role':"form" ,'novalidate':'novalidate', 'autocomplete':'off'}})}}

       {{ form_errors(form) }}

        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            {{ form_label(form.password, 'New Password:',{'label_attr':{'class': 'col-md-5'}}) }}

               <div class="col-md-7">

                {{ form_widget(form.password,{'attr':{'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'password','data-error': 'You must enter a minimum of 6 characters', 'placeholder': 'Min 6 characters', 'data-minlength':"6", 'required':'true' }}) }}

                <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        {{ form_row(form.submit,{'attr':{'class': 'btn btn-primary pull-right' }}) }}

        <div class="hidden">
            {{ form_rest(form) }}
        </div>
    {{ form_end(form) }}

...
```

The problem I have is that the input is not created. The label is displayed. I have tried using `form.password.first` and `form.password.second` but neither is the input (only the labels). With the other fields I do not have that problem, the only thing in this case all the others are hidden in a div. What could be the problem?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this. it is for symfony 2.8/3+ but you can adapt it to your needs.

> FormType

```
->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, [
    'type'           => PasswordType::class,
    'first_options'  => [
        'label' => 'registration.password',
    ],
    'second_options' => [
        'label' => 'registration.retype.password',
    ],
]) ...
```

> twig

```
<div>
    {{ form_label(form.plainPassword.first) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.first) }}
</div>

<div>
    {{ form_label(form.plainPassword.second) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.second) }}
</div>
```

Comment: The problem was that the same form was used as a parameter to the template for two different forms in the template, one to update the user data and another to update the password (hiding in both fields), as well as to display the fields The password on the second form did not appear anything to me.

Comment: @Joseph also try to format your code. you will not be able to see anything if you have your code spread all over. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a version of xDebug installed? You could place a breakpoint on the *return* section of the Controller and have a look inside the children element of the *form*. This could tell you what the names of the elements are.

**PS, I would have commented this but I don't have enough rep.